# Estimate the time to run the SQL Query

Tags: sql

I've a SQL Query to select the records from a table with some joins. The table contains millions of records.

How to estimate the time to run a SQL Query before executing it?

Comment: IF you're using Oracle, please have a look at https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=1049379

Answer (score 1):

Run the query with "top 10", then "top 100" then "top 1000", and so on. Once you reach a level where it takes around 10 seconds, you can divide up to get the estimated rows per second.

You should get a good idea from that how long it will take to run with all the rows.